# How to use Execute Javascript driver.findElement(By.xpath in Robot Framework

Tags: javascript, robotframework

I'm having a hard time trying to use Execute Javascript  `driver.findElement(By.xpath` in Robot Framework

I have no issues updating the value of an element using this JS method below

```
document.getElementById("Some_ID").value = "Some Value"
```

Robot can find the `document.getElementById` method but can't find the `driver.findElement(By.xpath`  method

Does anyone know how I would go about using the method/instantiating the driver?

The error I get is this:

> WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: driver is not defined

Comment: Have you initialized your robot? ie: Webdriver driver = new [...]
The error suggests that the script doesn't know `driver`

Comment: `driver.findElement()` is not a JS method, it is a selenium's one - thus the error.

Comment: can you show the actual code you're using? Do you have a python-based keyword that gives you access to `driver`?

Comment: Perhaps you can also elaborate on what it is you want to achieve functionally. Perhaps there is a better way of doing it without the need for custom javascript work.

Answer (score 1):

`driver.findElement(By.xpath)` is not a Javascript method. It is a method of Selenium. 
As you said, javascript only has `document.getElementById` method.

If you still want to use xpath with javascript method, use `Assign Id To Element` keyword (see more at [HERE](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Assign%20Id%20To%20Element)). It will assign an ID for an xpath locator. Then use that ID in `document.getElementById` method

Comment: This was perfect. Thank you very much!